# create sql server database as other sql database structure (design)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

I need to create sql database just like other sql database (without the data) via sql script

some one told me that Oracle has this ability by some code like

```
create database <your new DB name> as <the old DB name>
```

so is there a similar statement or workaround in SQL

I use MS-SQL Server 2008/2008R2

I don't want the 'generate scrip' solution as this provide a very long script, I just need the Oracle statement (mentioned above) but in SQL

to be more clear I need the tables structure only (no data) and need all other objects such as functions, views etc...

Please advice,

Comment: In SQL... you do realise that's the language and not the RDBMS right? Which do you mean - MySQL/SQL Server etc. ?

Comment: Be more specific: SQL Server, MySQL, PLSQL, TSQL?

Comment: @amrosama I've added tags with your rdbms for you - hopefully get you some more views/answers.

Comment: @amrosama Do you need the DB structure or the Data as well?

Comment: I need the database structure (no data) and need the procedures views etc...

Comment: And sometimes we can't have what we want.

Comment: @HLGEM so you mean it's not available in SQL Server?

Comment: @HLGEM so it seams like your answer is correct, so can you put it as answer not comment to mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about SQL Server (at least in 2005 or newer, not sure about previous versions) if you right click on a Database in SQL Server Management Studio Go To Tasks and then Generate Scripts you have the option to Generate a script to create all the object ins the Database w/o Data.

**Update:**
You can also right click on a User Database and select Script Database as -> Create To just to get the TSQL to create the DB itself without any of the tables, stored procedure etc.

Comment: thank you, but I don't want all this scripts I need some thing more simple like the oracle statment

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can right click on the database then select "Tasks" then "Generate Scripts" and you can build one script for all your object sans data.

Comment: thank you, but I don't want all this scripts I need some thing more simple like the oracle statment